# How to export a sheet with a dynamic sheet name

Tags: excel, vba, export

I am trying to export the sheet named Baby plus today's date. However, it is being exported as LValue. How can I fix this?

```
Sub Export()

    nameBaby = "Baby"
    nameToday = Format(Date, "MM.DD.YYYY")
    ActiveSheet.Name = nameBaby + " " + nameToday

     Dim myDate
     myDate = Date
     Dim LValue As String
     LValue = "Baby " & Format(myDate, "mm.dd.yyyy")

     Sheets(LValue).Select
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     Sheets(LValue).Move

ChDir "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Johnsons\Parallel"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Johnsons\Parallel\LValue.xlsx", FileFormat:= _
    xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the variable, it's just a string right now that happens to be the same as the variable.

```
"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Johnsons\Parallel\" & LValue & ".xlsx"
```

It may not like that your dates are formatted with a "."